# explain SQL Query with NOT IN etc

Tags: sql

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT callid) as r 
FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
        WHERE queuename = :queuename 
        AND time > :date 
        AND callid NOT IN (
             SELECT callid FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
             WHERE event IN ('CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 
                             'AGENTCALLBACKLOGOFF', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGIN'))
```

but i need to know exactly what it is doing, can anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sub query:**

```
SELECT callid FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
WHERE event IN ('CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGOFF', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGIN')
```

Selects the list of callids from voipwallboard_ast_queue_log table where event is any of `'CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGOFF', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGIN'`

**Main query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT callid) as r 
FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
    WHERE queuename = :queuename 
    AND time > :date 
    AND callid NOT IN (Sub query)
```

Selects the distinct count of callids where callid not in the sub query results and rest of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

it returns all the **unique** `callid` filtered by a specified `queuename` and `date` for ALL the events exept `CONNECT`, `ABANDON`, `AGENTCALLBACKLOGOFF` AND `AGENTCALLBACKLOGIN`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are counting callids(normally exclusive for one call but it can have a number of different events) from voipwallboard_ast_queue_log  but you are not counting callids whose events are 'CONNECT, ABANDON, AGENTCALLBACKLOGOFF, AGENTCALLBACKLOGIN)

You can specify a DATE and a queue name.

Answer (score 0):

It's counting the distinct calls for a :queuename as of a :date and excluding any calls where there was an event of `'CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGOFF', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGIN'` at ANY point of time or for ANY queuename.

Answer (score 0):

So the inner query (called a subquery) will run first, and return a single column (callid)  table which you can run more queries against.

The WHERE event IN clause simply means select only the rows where the event attribute is one of these ('CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGOFF', 'AGENTCALLBACKLOGIN').

Once that query returns the single column table, the outer query will return the count of rows returned where queuename is the queuename you've specified, it is greater than the date you've specified, and callid does NOT show up in the previous query.

You are also using the DISTINCT keyword, so duplicate rows will be excluded from the count.